# Gemfile is not using the specified ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, rbenv, gemfile

I'm making a project and when I run a generate command I get the following error:

```
fullpath: /Users/adamgoldberg/shopify-sinatra-app/theappearsystemcontrol6
Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2
Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch: Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2
  /Users/adamgoldberg/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:417:in `validate_ruby!'
  /Users/adamgoldberg/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:91:in `setup'
  /Users/adamgoldberg/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/adamgoldberg/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /Users/adamgoldberg/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'bundler: failed to load command: rake (/Users/adamgoldberg/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rake)
```

I have to use ruby version 2.3.1 for my project so I have attempted changing my Gemfile version.
my gemfile now contains this:

```
ruby "~> 2.3"
```

I have tried all sorts of commands so that the Gemfile recognises that I want to use a different ruby version. I have tried:

```
bundle update
bundle install
gem bundle install
rbenv rehash
```

even my Gemfile.lock says it is using 2.3.1:

```
RUBY VERSION
    ruby 2.3.1p112
```

I have even deleted the project and started again.

Please help

---

An update: I deleted the project and restarted. here are the exact steps I took from my home directory

```
ruby -v: #2.3.1
git clone https://github.com/kevinhughes27/shopify-sinatra-app.git
gem install shopify-sinatra-app
shopify-sinatra-app-generator new myshop
```

and the same error as above appeared:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2
```

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gemspec
```

it's practically empty... I haven't even specified the ruby version
I then ran

```
bundle install 
bundle update
```

still the same error appears.
I then specified in my Gemspect the ruby version and it now looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.3.1"
gemspec
```

but still the same error appears

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use version specifiers like that for the Ruby version. I've never seen any examples with that.

Perhaps try it like this if you want v2.3.1:

```
ruby "2.3.1"
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. just tried it and used bundle update... my gemfile now says: ruby "2.3.1"

Answer (score 0):

The attempt you're taking here:

```
ruby "~> 2.3"
```

seems like the right approach, but you should use an exact Ruby version:

```
ruby "2.3.1"
```

It's worth mentioning that you don't necessarily need to manually specify your ruby version anywhere if you don't want to.

---

*updated answer*

i cloned the gem and tried installing it. I got the same error. I figured out where the source of the `2.2.2` dependency is. It's in the gem's source code, which for me is `~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/shopify-sinatra-app-0.3.0`. In `examples/Gemfile` there is a `ruby '2.2.2'` line.

I tried removing this line, but there was a different error installing activesupport. I think it's likely that the easiest solution for generating an app with this gem would be to install ruby 2.2.2

Comment: So I deleted the project and started from scratch -- here are the exact steps i took...

Comment: where are the exact steps you took? Also, did you look for a `.ruby-version` file in your repo?

Comment: I made an edit to the question which outlines the exact steps.